# Remote tracking branches confusion

Tags: git, version-control

I've been playing around with http://git-school.github.io/visualizing-git and I'm not really sure how this works - can I delete remote tracking branches? Say I have local branches `master` and `origin/master` and a remote repository with `master` branch that corresponds to the local `origin/master`.

Can I delete `origin/master` ? If I can and I do so, how do I set up a new remote tracking branch for it again? Would just fetching `origin` automatically create it again? If someone pushes some new branch onto the remote repository say `feature`, will `fetch` always download this automatically and create a remote tracking branch `origin/feature` in my local repository? Does `fetch` always download "everything on remote repo that you're missing"?

Lastly, I know you can set what remote tracking branch a local branch tracks, say `git branch -u origin/feature` (assuming I have `feature` checked out) will associate `feature` with `origin/feature`, both local branches. In this case we call `origin/feature` the upstream branch. But can I change which remote branch `origin/feature` is associated with, and is this association also called "upstream" ?

I'm mostly just curious and I haven't been really able to recreate the remote tracking branch on the site I linked, after I tried deleting it. But maybe it's as simple as "fetch always creates a new remote tracking branch if it doesn't exist in your local repository".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... can I delete remote tracking branches?

Yes, but there is little point (not quite *no* point, just "little").  The command-line command to do this is, e.g.:

```
git branch -r -d origin/master
```

(though you might have to force the delete in some cases).

Let's be overly explicit here and define *remote-tracking branch name* (or as I prefer to call it, *remote-tracking name*) carefully first, just in case.  A remote-tracking name is a name that exists in *your* repository, but whose full name—as shown by, e.g., `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name` or `git for-each-ref`—starts with `refs/remotes/` (and goes on to include the name of a remote such as `origin` and another slash).  These routinely get abbreviated to things like `origin/master` (though for some reason `git branch -a` abbreviates them as `remotes/origin/master` instead—compare to `git branch -r` which uses the shorter form).

> If I ... do [delete `origin/master`], how do I set up a new remote tracking branch for it again? Would just fetching origin automatically create it again?

In general, yes.

> If someone pushes some new branch onto the remote repository say `feature`, will fetch always download this automatically and create a remote tracking branch `origin/feature` in my local repository?

In general, yes.

> Does fetch always download "everything on remote repo that you're missing"?

Mostly.

> Lastly, I know you can set what remote tracking branch a local branch tracks, say `git branch -u origin/feature` (assuming I have `feature` checked out) will associate `feature` with `origin/feature`, both local branches.

Yes, though be careful about the phrase "local branches": `origin/feature` is a name specific to your *repository* but Git tends to call it a *remote-tracking branch name*, which leads to casual (mis?)use of the word *branch*, which is why I like to just drop the word *branch* entirely here now and call it a *remote-tracking name*.  That way instead of being tempted to call it a "local branch", you'll be tempted to call it a "local name", which I think is much clearer.

> In this case we call `origin/feature` the upstream branch.

I prefer to just call it the *upstream* (again, trying to avoid beating the poor word *branch* to death :-) ).

> But can I change which remote branch `origin/feature` is associated with ...

No, or not really: a remote-tracking name has no association, at least not of this kind.

> and is this association also called "upstream"?

Without the association, we don't need a term for it. :-)

#### How this works under the hood

When you have your Git call up another Git, you supply a set of *refspecs*—optionally on the command line, but you always supply them.  This is true even if you use a raw URL.  The general form of a command-line `git fetch` command is:

```
git fetch [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

That is, there are optional *`options`* arguments (like `--tags` or `--no-tags`, and/or `--prune`, and so on), an optional *`repository`* argument, and optional *`refspec`* arguments.  To supply a *`refspec`* argument, you *must* first supply the *`repository`* argument, as these are positional arguments: the first non-option argument *is* the repository, and subsequent non-options *are* refspecs.  So:

```
git fetch origin
```

supplies a *`repository`* argument and no *`refspec`* arguments, and:

```
git fetch origin '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
```

supplies one *`repository`* and then one *`refspec`*.

The *`repository`* argument *can* be a URL, but these days, generally *should* be a *remote*.  A remote is simply a short name like `origin`.  Git stores at least two items under this short name:

- `remote.remote.url` contains the URL that Git can use for fetch and push operations;
- `remote.remote.pushurl` (if set) contains an alternate URL Git should use instead for `git push`; and
- `remote.remote.fetch` contains the refspec arguments that Git should use, if you don't provide any on the command line.

All these settings are stored in your configuration, as shown by `git config -l` for instance.<sup>1</sup>  The act of creating a remote—via `git remote add`, for instance—will automatically create both the URL and fetch settings for that new remote.  When you run `git clone`, Git creates a remote, as if by `git remote add`, so that too sets the two usual settings.  The default name of this automatically-created remote is `origin`, so that's why a Git repository usually has an `origin`: most Git repositories tend to be created via cloning.  Even those that aren't tend to have a `git remote add origin` run in them at some point.

Note that if you don't supply a remote or URL *`repository`* argument, `git fetch` will construct one: it will take the current branch's *remote* setting (`git config --get branch.branch.remote`, where *`branch`* is the current branch) to find the remote to use, or, as a last-ditch fallback, just use the hardcoded string `origin`.  So the default `git fetch` action is to find the correct remote name, or use `origin`, then use the `remote.remote.url` and `remote.remote.fetch` settings from there.

One way or another, then, you've run `git fetch` or `git fetch origin` *and* supplied one or more *refspecs*.  **It is the refspecs that determine what remote-tracking names will be created.**  The *default* refspec for the remote named `origin` is:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

We can disassemble this refspec into its component parts:

- an optional leading plus sign `+`, followed by
- a *source* and a *destination* separated by a colon `:` character

where either *source* or *destination* (but not both, at least not sensibly) can be omitted.  Both the source and destination parts can use an asterisk `*` in a way that's similar to, though not precisely the same as, a shell glob.<sup>2</sup>

The leading plus sign, if present, sets the *force flag* for this refspec.  This force flag is the same flag you get with `--force`, except that the `--force` option sets it for the duration of the entire `git fetch` operation, while the plus sign sets it only for the duration of this one particular refspec.

So, the default `origin` refspec:

- sets the force flag;
- asks for sources that match `refs/heads/*`; and
- uses a destination of `refs/remotes/origin/*`.

This destination is precisely the set of remote-tracking names for the remote `origin`, and *that's* where `origin/master` comes from.  The process is a bit convoluted, though.

At the start of the conversation your Git has with the other Git—the one at the URL—*their* Git lists out all their branch and tag names, plus any other `refs/*` type names: all their *refs* or *references*.<sup>3</sup>  This list comes with hash IDs, because each ref always stores one hash ID.  It's slightly augmented for tag refs (`refs/tags/*`).  To see exactly what their Git spills out that this point, you can run `git ls-remote origin`, which does this first fetch step: call up the other Git and have it list out its refs.  Then instead of *fetching*, `git ls-remote` just prints the list of refs.

Now that your `git fetch` has its paws on *their* refs, now *your* Git goes to apply the refspecs.  Which of their refs match your refspecs?  Those are the ones that your Git will inspect more closely.<sup>4</sup>

At this point, your Git inspects the *hash IDs* they gave you.  Hash IDs are the universal currency of Git exchanges, because *every* Git in the universe agrees that any one particular hash ID is going to apply to that one particular object.<sup>5</sup>  Either you have the object already, in which case you have that hash ID in your own repository too, or you don't, in which case you don't.  If you *don't* have the hash ID and *do* want some commit here, your Git tells their Git that, yes, it wants that hash ID.  Assuming this is a commit, or annotated tag object—most of these are; see footnote 5—their Git will offer its parent(s) or, for a tag, its tag-target, and your Git can again say whether it wants the object, or not.

This process—the exchange of hash IDs, and "want" vs "already have" kind of responses—makes up the second phase of `git fetch`.  Eventually your Git has told their Git which objects—commits and any necessary files to go with them—that they should package up and send; and now your `git fetch`, and their end, go into a third phase, of building what Git calls a *thin pack*.  This is where you see "counting objects" and "compressing objects" and so on (if you do see them at all—this stuff is run off a timer and some of it is suppressed in some cases).

Finally, they send you this thin pack.  Your Git takes the thin pack and "fattens" it into a regular pack, or otherwise incorporates the objects into your own repository.  You now have all the objects you need from them, along with all of the hash IDs that correspond to all of the *names* your Git got from their Git.  So if their `refs/heads/master`—their `master` branch—names commit `a1234567...`, and you didn't have `a1234567...` before, well, now you do.  You also have the *parent* commits, and their parents, all the way back to the dawn of time, if needed.<sup>6</sup>  Typically, though, their `a1234567...`, if new, is only new for a few commits in length, after which the parent chain leads back into something you got from them yesterday, or whenever—so instead of fetching thousands of commits, you just fetch one, or three, or a dozen, or whatever.

In any case, the conversation with their Git is now done.  Your Git has all the objects (commits and associated files) that your Git needs, along with the list of their branch names.  Your Git now *creates or updates* your *remote-tracking names* via the refspec you supplied, either on the command line, or implicitly in via your configuration.

---

<sup>1</sup>Normally these should be in the `--local` level, although Git itself doesn't care where they come from: it's just weird to set these in your system or global config.  The URL and (if specified) push-URL are "last setting overrides" style configuration entries, but the `fetch` lines are cumulative settings.  That is, if you've set these rather nonsense settings:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch foo:bar
git config --add remote.origin.fetch baz:quux
```

then `git fetch origin` acts like `git fetch origin foo:bar baz:quux`.  So adding a `remote.origin.fetch` setting to your `--global` configuration would *add* to the standard setting, and this is potentially useful, but also potentially hazardous: you'll need to think hard about doing it.

<sup>2</sup>The degree of similarity depends on your Git vintage, as some restrictions were lifted in early 2.x versions.

<sup>3</sup>More precisely, their Git lists references that have not been marked *hidden*.  Normally there are no hidden refs anyway, though.

<sup>4</sup>The process is modified a bit for tags, because `--tags` and `--no-tags` are not the default, and the default is kind of weird and surprising, but is why the tag information that the other Git hands over is augmented in the first place.  I won't go into details here though.

<sup>5</sup>You mostly interact with hash IDs when talking about *commit* objects.  These are just one of four internal object types, but they're the most important here, and *branch names*, such as `refs/heads/master`, are constrained: they *must* contain only *commit* hash IDs, not tree or blob or annotated-tag object hash IDs.  However, internally, `git fetch` has ways of dealing with tree and blob hash IDs as well, to avoid re-sending file content that you already have, for instance.  The details are well out of the scope of this answer.

<sup>6</sup>All of this gets modified, if desired, via what Git calls a *shallow clone*.  In a shallow clone, some specific commits are omitted, which allows omitting all the history that comes before those commits.  Shallow clones have some restrictions.  The details again depend on exact Git vintage, though most of the strongest restrictions were lifted by Git version 2.0.

---

#### This is where all the caveats and "in general" items above come from

Using the standard `remote.origin.fetch`, then, this is where your Git creates or updates your `origin/master` based on what their Git said about their `master`.  If you have a standard `fetch` setting, your Git will take *all* of their branches and create-or-update *all* of your remote-tracking names, using this one-to-one correspondence: their `master` becomes your `origin/master`; their `feature` becomes your `origin/feature`.

The mapping is determined by the refspecs, though.  So you can create a *single-branch* clone, and in this single-branch clone you'll have:

```
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

for instance.  Now your Git *only* matches their `refs/heads/master` (plus some cases of tags, but see footnote 4).  So you only get your `origin/master` created-or-updated.

To de-single-branch-ize this clone, you can simply change the default refspec.  Or, to fetch *two* branches, but still just those two, you can add a second `remote.origin.fetch` line:

```
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/dev:refs/remotes/origin/dev
```

Now, while a remote-tracking name has no *upstream* setting—the upstream setting of a (regular, local) branch is in its `branch.branch.remote` and `branch.branch.merge` settings, and there's nothing equivalent for remote-tracking names—it *is* possible to set up a wildly convoluted set of refspecs.  It's not a good idea, though.

Note how we mentioned above the concept of doing a one-to-one mapping from their Git's names (`refs/heads/*`) to your remote-tracking names (`refs/remotes/origin/*`).  If you do this:

```
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master2
```

you would get *two* remote-tracking names from one source.  Or, with:

```
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/dev:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

you would get *one* remote-tracking name from *two* sources.

This is bad, because it means the mapping is not reversible.  If we want to go from `origin/master` to "the branch name they use over on `origin`", is that `master` or `dev`?  Or, if we want to go from `master`-on-`origin` to our remote-tracking equivalent, is that `master` or `master2`?

In some ambiguous cases, Git will just give up and do nothing.  Moreover, you can use `--prune`, or set the option `fetch.prune` to `true`, and in this case, after handling:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

your Git will comb through any `refs/remotes/origin/*` names that you have that *weren't* created-or-updated-or-at-least-refreshed by *this* `git fetch` operation, and remove them.  This doesn't work right without a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection): the algorithm is basically "do an injection, then remove untouched names if the injection was surjective".

Without `--prune`, your Git just leaves these "stale" remote-tracking names behind.  That's why there's *little*, but not *no*, point to removing remote-tracking names.  If you don't use `-p` or `--prune` or set `fetch.prune` to `true`, you may accumulate these stale branches.  Using `git branch -r -d` will allow you to delete them.  If you delete some by mistake, a subsequent `git fetch` will restore them, assuming a normal `fetch` setting.

I just do a `git config --global fetch.prune true` to set it as the default, though.